# Many to Many relationship yielding wrong total

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Let's assume I have two tables one called `Schools` and one called `Invoices`.

They have a many to many relationship with a single cross filter direction which means if I filter a school it should give me the `NetAmount` from the `Invoices` table.

However, when I put the `NetAmount` into a card visual and use 3 columns from the `Schools` table to filter it, I get an incorrect sum.

[image]

[image]

Is there any particular reason why I am not getting the correct value? Which should actually be `£43,772.85`.

Comment: Please show us some ras data and how you conclude your 43,772.85 is correct. Try to figure out where the 276,624.15 is coming from..

Comment: Your measure is just a simple sum or something more complex? Probably, because of many to many relationship you "count" some invoices twice or more.

Comment: its not even a measure i'm simply adding the NetAmount from the invoice table into a card visual which then does a sum automatically

Comment: So, basically I found out that the figure £276,624.15 is the total for the school for all the years combined, so its not taking into account that I have filtered on just electricity and for the year 2021.

Comment: Try creating a measure using this script - then put this measure in your card visual and use the same filters: 
TestNetAmount:= CALCULATE(
    SUM( Invoices[NetAmount] ),
    Schools
)

Comment: I tried that and it gives the total amount for the school but when I filter for a specific year the total does not change